# Drop down list with foreach iteration PHP

Tags: php, html

all

I'm having little problem with  : I want to make dynamic drop down list and I write this:

```
<select name='categoryID' >
    <?php foreach( $categories as $category)?>
    <option value="<?php echo $category['id']?>"> <?php echo $category['name'] ?></option>
</select>
```

The problem is that foreach doesen't work properly: enters only 1 time. I need to mark that when i dump categories list it shows all items. Any suggestions why is this happen? Is that a right way to make drop down list?

whole code:
http://pastebin.com/RE56KQCY

Comment: If the braces are omitted, only the first statement after the `foreach` statement will be executed in the loop. Add braces to make sure all the `echo` statements are executed.

Comment: also use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` functions, because they are depreciated. U can also read a little bit about DAB in internet which helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get only one row because you haven't closed your breckets.

**Note**: I find it really easy to use [short_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php), `foreach(/.../): endforeach;`

*P.S.*

*I'm not quite sure I have the rights to write this here, but I looked at your code I noticed few problems:*

1) You have a connection to DB in the exact file you are using the results. It may be appropriate in your case. Not quite sure.
Common practice is to separate your logic and the layer that represents the data you have fetched.

2) You are using `mysql_*` which is deprecated since `PHP 5.5.0`.

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future.

Instead of `mysql_*` you can use `PDO` or `MySQLi`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php foreach( $categories as $category): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $category['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you forget to add brackets for [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
<select name='categoryID' >
    <?php foreach( $categories as $category){?>
    <option value="<?= $category['id']?>"> <?= $category['name'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```